# MVC - Choose different home page based on a configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web portal. In some deployment scenarios I want the default page to be a generic login page and in other deployment scenarios I would like it be a specific page for a service the portal provides.

However from the users point of view I would like them just to go to http://MYPORTAL/ without having to put choose anything else in the URL

I would like this to be based on a configuration - preferably in the web.config. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and this is where MVC comes in. In MVC, Controller is responsible for this sort of tasks. Controller can return different views on demand.

So basically in your Controller's method you will have a if or switch statement which will evaluate a condition and will return View based on that.